# Tricky demonstration

Tags: linear-algebra

this is what I'm trying to demonstrate

With the following system of $n \times n$ equations

$G_1B_1+G_2B_2+\cdots+G_nB_n=G_1A_1+G_2A_2+\cdots+G_nA_n$

$B_1-B_2=A_2-A_1$

$B_2-B_3=A_3-A_2$

$\vdots  \hspace{1cm} \vdots \hspace{1cm} \vdots \hspace{1cm} \vdots  $

$B_{n-1}-B_{n}=A_n-A_{n-1}$

Prove that in general any $B_{V}$ with $V \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ is equal to:

$B_V=\left(\Gamma_1A_1+\Gamma_2A_2+\cdots+\Gamma_nA_n\right)-A_V$

With $\Gamma_V=\dfrac{2G_V}{G1+G_2+\cdots+G_n}$

This is my first time solving a problem like that, so the first thing that I tried, was to write the system in a matrix form

$\left( \begin{array}{cccccc}
 G_1 & G_2 & G_3 & G_4 & \cdots & G_{n-1} & G_n \\ 
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array} \right)$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
 B_1 \\ 
 B_2 \\
 B_3 \\
 B_4 \\
 \vdots \\
 B_{n-1}\\
 B_n
\end{array} \right)$=$\left( \begin{array}{cccccc}
 G_1 & G_2 & G_3 & G_4 & \cdots & G_{n-1} & G_n \\ 
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right)$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
 A_1 \\ 
 A_2 \\
 A_3 \\
 A_4 \\
 \vdots \\
 A_{n-1}\\
 A_n
\end{array} \right)$

But it gets me nowhere and I think that it isn't the right approach to achieve that demonstration, This is not a book exercise, is just a formula that I found in a paper and that I don't understant how was obtained.

This is the paper https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jingjiez/portfolio/gtr-amp-sim/pdfs/Wave%20Digital%20Filters%20Theory%20and%20Practice.pdf , equation (29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should note that 
$$
A_1+B_1=
A_2+B_2=
\dots =
A_n + B_n.
$$

Now starting from the first given equation we have
$$
0=
\sum_i G_i (A_i -B_i)=
-\sum_i G_i (A_i +B_i)
+\sum_i G_i (A_i +B_i)
+\sum_i G_i (A_i -B_i)
$$
so that
$$
0=
-\sum_i G_i (A_i +B_i)
+2\sum_i G_i A_i,
$$
or
$$
\sum_i G_i (A_i +B_i)=
2\sum_i G_i A_i.
$$

Now recall that $A_i+B_i$ does not depend on $i$; we can replace them all by $A_j+B_j$ for a fixed $j$ and get:
$$
\left(\sum_i G_i\right) (A_j +B_j)=
2\sum_i G_i A_i
$$
which is what you wanted to prove.